# Hive, SQL: Return COUNT of NULL values for each of 100+ columns in a Hive table

Tags: sql, hive

What is the SQL code that returns the COUNT of NULL values for each of 100+ columns in a Hive table?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL it would be

```
 SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN a is null then 1 else 0 end) as a_null_count,
   SUM(CASE WHEN b is null then 1 else 0 end) as b_null_count,       
   --- ...
   SUM(CASE WHEN z is null then 1 else 0 end) as z_null_count
 FROM table
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid typing each of the column names?

Comment: @user2205916 - you could write a query using meta data to generate the sql statement.  -- select from the columns view and create the sum statements.

Comment: `else 0` is not necessary here in case statements

Comment: @leftjoin -- which do you think will be faster explicitly giving a value or letting the exception handler put in a default?

Comment: @Hogan It depends. If non of when clauses is true CASE returns NULL. SUM do not counts nulls and should not even receive those values if executed on reducer. But I'm not sure how does it really work. have never noticed a difference in performance, but without those `else 0` text is shorter

Comment: @leftjoin - you called me on it -- and I thought about it again -- I've found, in general the more information you give the compiler the better -- however, there won't be an exception handler since it is compiled.  I'm revising my position to agree with you --  does not matter at all in performance and is just a style thing.